# Pandas DataFrame Select a specific column with index tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe that looks like this

| firm | q | otheropexp | extraincome | incometax | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPL | 2021q2 | Three | 0 | 500 | ... |
|  | 2021q3 | 52 | 0 | 500 | ... |
|  | 2021q4 | 84 | 10 | 200 | ... |
|  | 2022q1 | 62 | -20 | 600 | ... |
|  | 2022q2 | 36 | 25 | 400 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ZY | 2021q2 | Three | 0 | 500 | ... |
|  | 2021q3 | 52 | 0 | 500 | ... |
|  | 2021q4 | 84 | 10 | 200 | ... |
|  | 2022q1 | 62 | -20 | 600 | ... |

and what I want to achieve is to only get the columns of "q" = "2022q1", from each "firm",
What can I do?

Note - I set my index "firm" and "q", by using this script

`df_Services.set_index(['firm', 'q'], inplace = True)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reassign df_Services to: `df_Services = df_Services[df_Services['q'] == '2022q1']`

Then you will be able to set the index: `df_Services.set_index(['firm', 'q'], inplace=True)`

**Output:** `print(df_Services)`

```
            otheropexp  extraincome  incometax
firm q
APPL 2022q1         62          -20        600
ZY   2022q1         62          -20        600
```